# App Engine callback for new user "registration" / user login?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid, python-2.7

I'm using Google App Engine's default User service for authentication right now.  I would like to be able to store the join date for a user (i.e. how long the user has been a member of my web app) and be able to ban users from my app if they misbehave.

I understand that I will need an additional model to store this information:

```
class User_Info(db.model):
  user = db.UserProperty()
  join_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  banned = db.BooleanProperty(False)
```

But what I don't understand: is there a way is to get a callback for when a new user "registers" for my app (to store the join date) or logs in (to check if user has been banned)?

One method I thought of was to send in a intermediary destination URL to the `users.create_login_url()`, which would check if an associated User_Info instance existed.  If it did, it would check the banned flag.  If not, it would create a user_info instance and store the join date.  It would then redirect to the actual destination url.

Is there a better solution?

Note that I will switch over to the federated authentication model in the future and was hoping for a solution that would work when I did switch over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the right way to do it.